# IPython 4 Breaking Public Server on EC2

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Recently upgraded to IPython 4.0 with conda but no longer can get my notebook to serve on a public URL as before using `ipython notebook --profile=nbserver`
Now I get `Unrecognized alias: '--profile=nbserver', it will probably have no effect.` and `The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/` which isn't correct. Considering re-initializing the config files but wanted to check on SO first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can just run

```
ipython notebook --config='~/.ipython/profile_nbserver/ipython_notebook_config.py'
```